# OpenLayers are not rendering MapServer layer

Tags: openlayers, mapserver

I have a MapServer layer, Roads in this instance, and I've set its STATUS to ON. I want to render this as a WMS service using OpenLayers. So I've set all the Metadata Section in the LAYER section in the MAP file. Then in OpenLayers I have the following snippet:

```
 var params = {
              LAYERS: 'Roads',
              FORMAT: 'image/png',
              VERSION: '1.1.1',
       }

       var source = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/user/mapdata/fifth.map&layer=Roads',
          params: params
       });

       var layer = new ol.layer.Image({
            source: source     
       });

       var center = ol.proj.transform([21.768006, 39.556202], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

       var view = new ol.View({
              center: center,
              zoom: 15
       });


       var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            view: view,
            renderer: 'dom'
       });

       map.addLayer(layer);
```

However, the layer is never rendered, although in the url I pass the layer=Roads parameter. 
If I set the STATUS to default in the map file everything works well but in this occasion, not. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe related: `renderer: 'dom'` has been removed e.g https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v3.19.0

Comment: hmm... I commented it out. Still the same... :\

Comment: Do you see any call to MapServer in Network tab of Chrome/FF debugger?

Comment: I think so... in Network tab in the name section I see four five files being called. My html file, ol.js, ol.css,  data/image:png;base...  and the call to MapServer like 'mapserv?map=/home/user.....' (huge WMS link) In there there's parameter LAYERS=Roads. I guess it's the value of the params variable?

Comment: On the WMS call in the same Network tab, right click and then choose "Open in a new tab" to debug your MapServer call.

Comment: This action downloads and xml file that's showing me this error: msWMSLoadGetMapParams(): WMS server error. Invalid SRS given : SRS must be valid for all requested layers

Comment: So, your issue is in MapServer not related to OpenLayers itself. At least, you know.

Comment: According to the WMS GetCapabilities response, what coordinate reference systems are supported? You can only request one of those CRS/SRS in your OpenLayers GetMap request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters should be:
 var params = {
              'LAYERS': 'Roads',
              'FORMAT': 'image/png',
              'VERSION': '1.1.1',
       }

Comment: Thanks. I changed it but still nothing. The layer won't be rendered

Comment: Are you sure your wms server support the projection EPSG:3857 ?

Comment: hem...no. I've set the "wms_srs" to "EPSG:2100" (in the METADATA section of the MAP level). Should I add 3857 too? Can we add two "wms_srs" parameters. And if yes where should it be added? In the LAYER level metadata or the MAP level metadata ?

Comment: Well, two suggestions: 1. try EPSG:2100 in openlayers3 to see if layer displayed or not.  2. add EPSG:3857 to both of the above metadata sections

Comment: Read the official doc e.g `By default layers inherit the SRS of their parent layer (the map’s PROJECTION in the MapServer case). For this reason it is not necessary (but still strongly recommended) to provide PROJECTION and wms_srs for every layer. If a layer PROJECTION is not provided then the top-level map projecion will be assumed.` See section http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_server.html#setup-a-mapfile-for-your-wms to see an example with multiple SRS

Answer (score 0):

Put all the projection you need in the web section of your mapfile

```
WEB
    METADATA
        'wms_enable_request'  '*'
        # Allow WMS service to serve multiple projections
        # Only EPSG, AUTO2, CRS codes are supported as part of WMS 1.3.0
        'wms_srs' 'EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857 EPSG:54009'
    END
END
```

Source from [Mapserver doc](https://geographika.github.io/tutorial/quickstart/projections.html)